# tomcat7 maven plugin publishing error

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, tomcat7-maven-plugin

I am trying to use mvn tomcat7:deploy . Every thing is working good and it is deploying the application but in the log file it shows

> FAIL - Failed to deploy application ...

How does the plugin check if the deployment is successful or no

```
[INFO] Building war: /home/ali.XXXX/XXXX-XXXX/target/XXXX-0.0.3-SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.2.5.RELEASE:repackage (default) @ XXXX ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:deploy (default-cli) < package @ XXXX <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:deploy (default-cli) @ XXXX ---
[INFO] Deploying war to https://app.XXXX.com/ROOT/#20151029083954  
Uploading: https://app.XXXX.com/manager/text/deploy?path=%2FROOT%2F%2320151029083954
Uploaded: https://app.XXXX.com/manager/text/deploy?path=%2FROOT%2F%2320151029083954 (40309 KB at 13512.7 KB/sec)

[INFO] tomcatManager status code:200, ReasonPhrase:OK
[INFO] FAIL - Failed to deploy application at context path /ROOT/#20151029083954
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 33.053 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-10-29T08:40:27+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 35M/356M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: check whether tomcat deployment folder is ROOT or else

Comment: Can you copy your web.xml ?

Comment: i don't have web.xml in the application as i use spring-boot

Comment: @Shahbour I am also getting same  error. Did you find a solution ?

Comment: No still the same